# How to insert geography type data using bigquery insert method with nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

I am using Node library for integration with BigQuery. Wanted to know how I can store Geography datatype values in Table  using Table.insert method. I tried few thing like below but gives error

```
const options = {
datasetId: 'mydataset',
tableId: 'mytable', 
rows: [
  {
    rec1:"raj",
    rec2:"geography::Point('-6', '6', 4326)"
  }
] }

const table = await bigqueryClient
.dataset(options.datasetId)
.table(options.tableId) 
table.insert(options.rows, (err, resp) => {
if (err) {
  console.log('*****err', err)
} else {
  console.log('*****resp', resp)
}  })
```

Or only way to achieve this is using query method on BigQuery client with query in below format ?

```
insert `bigqueryproject1-279307.mydataset.mytable` (rec1,rec2) values ('raj', ST_GEOGPOINT(-6, 6) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create table with schema first. Something like [this](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/master/samples/insertingDataTypes.js)

```
const schema = [
    {
    name: 'rec1',
    type: 'STRING',
    },
    {
    name: 'rec2',
    type: 'GEOGRAPHY',
    }
];
    
const options = {
    schema: schema,
};

const [table] = await bigquery
    .dataset('mydataset')
    .createTable('mytable', options);
```

Then try to insert data with GEOG data types. I recommend to use geom data in format of geojson while wkt format is sometimes not imported correctly (from my experience)

```
{    
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        -6,
        6
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Jozef, you mean pass on value like this ?   const options = {
    datasetId: 'mycreatedataset1',
    tableId: 'newTabelwithAllDatatype', 
    rows: [
      {
        rec1:"raj",
  rec11:{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
     -6, 6] }
   } 
  } ]  
 }
while creating new row ?

Comment: yes something like this but stringify your JSON and use it like string

Comment: i get below error  "Cannot convert value '{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-6,6]}}' to GEOGRAPHY: GeoJSON reader accepts Geometry objects, not Feature or FeatureCollection objects","reason":"invalid"}],"row":{"id":"sidd","location":"{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-6,6]}}"}}],"name"

Comment: ouc my bad, I corrected my answer. You need only json inside geometry

Comment: Got it working using this format {
         "type": "GeometryCollection",
         "geometries": [{
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [-70, 50]
         }]
     }

Comment: yes, but if your GeometryCollection contains only one point, { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -6, 6 ] } should work as well

Comment: Setting to geojson format didn't work for me using python client bigquery.Client().insert_rows()  - had to set it to string "'POINT(-6 6)'" and that worked perfect

Comment: @Sia, could  you please share a snippet of your implementation in python?